# Program to open an Apple Keynote (.key) file in Windows or Linux

Tags: document-converter, presentation

I'm looking for a program than can:

- open an Apple Keynote (`.key`) file in Windows

And if possible:

- free
- works on Windows 7 or Linux
- can also edit the file

I currently use https://www.zamzar.com/ to convert the .key to PDF online, but it is a bit slow. Also, since the `.key` is a zip archive I can unzip to see thumbnails for each slide but they are small.

Comment: You can open the Keynote in http://icloud.com and then download as PowerPoint / PDF

Comment: Thanks, good to know, but can I register to icloud online and for free? Apparently it is not possible http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4436 (in which case I can just borrow some iOS ISO and register)

Comment: I thought you could, but unfortunately you can't. I guess you could 'borrow' somebody's iPhone/Mac and sign up. Most people I know have an iOS device, or know somebody with one, so that shouldn't be a problem. Not sure how you would go about installing an IOS ISO...?

Comment: e.g. http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox

Comment: Oh, you said iOS, not OSX ;) Also, if you do that, it's a real pain, trust me - I've tried, succeffully, but it never works first time!

Comment: Also, in case anybody was wondering, icloud.com is run by Apple, the same company that makes keynote. Of course, you will need to have an Apple ID. If you have an iPhone or an iPad (even if you don't have a Mac) you will have an Apple ID.

Comment: The iCloud Keynote doesn't seem to work under Chrome on Ubuntu...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open the .keynote file online at [iCloud](http://icloud.com) and export it (Apple now allows you to sign up online *without* an Apple device!).

It will ask you to sign up at the top of the homepage, from which you can enter your details and use Keynote/Pages/Numbers online.

You can then view it as a PDF on Windows/OS X/Linux.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with presentations over 1GB, as this is the space available in a new account.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/) and you will convert to whatever you want,
No need for Apple any more